# Javascript show/hide div requires two clicks

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've got code to show/hide two divs based upon the clicking of an arrow.  However, the second div requires two clicks before it hides and the arrow doesn't change as expected.  The top div works perfectly.  Any suggestions about what I'm doing wrong, please?

**EDIT** - Thanks to the two posters who have pointed out my naming error in the arrows.  However, after loading the page, the second div still requires two clicks before it toggles.

**HTML**

```
<div id="start_conditions_arrow" class="arrow_down" onclick="toggleDiv('start_conditions')"></div>
<h2>Starting Conditions</h2>

<div id="start_conditions">
    <%= render :partial => 'start_conditions', :object => @page.start_conditions %>
</div>

<div id="probability_arrow" class="arrow_right" onclick="toggleDiv('probability_inputs')"></div>
<h2>Probability Inputs</h2>

<div id="probability_inputs">
    <%= render :partial => 'probability_inputs', :object => @page.probability_inputs %>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var toggleDiv = function(id){
var tag = document.getElementById(id).style;
    if(tag.display == 'none'){
        document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById(id + '_arrow').className='arrow_down';
    } else {            
        document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
        document.getElementById(id + '_arrow').className='arrow_right';
    }
};
```

**CSS**

```
.arrow_down, .arrow_right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    margin: 12px 12px 0 0;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow_down {
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 18px solid #d5d5d5;
}

.arrow_right {
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 18px solid #d5d5d5;
}

#probability_inputs {
    display: none;
}

#start_conditions {
    display: none;
}
```

Here's a Codepen including the above: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXozYJ

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't provide a link to this snippet of an internal Rails app without displaying proprietary internal data.  I hope I've provided enough code to determine why it's not functioning as I expect.  Please let me know if you need to see any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that I'm a little late answering this, but I have a solution. There are two issues that should be addressed and they're as follows:

- The ID of the last `div` is incorrect as stated in PSR's answer.
- The check against the style attribute of the element in the `toggleDiv` method doesn't account for the lacking of the style attribute upon page load.

Regarding the first issue, the ID should read `probability_inputs_arrow`, which fixes the issue with the arrow not being updated when it is toggled. However, the second issue needs a little more explaining...

Upon page load, the CSS provided is applied to the elements with the IDs `probability_inputs` and `start_conditions`, giving them both a display value of none. Upon clicking on either one of these arrows, you're retrieving the style attributes of the targeted element, and checking the display property *which upon page load is empty*. This is why it requires two clicks to achieve the desired behaviour, because the first click is effectively just setting that value in the else statement.

> Here's a link to an updated Codepen that contains the fixes: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oweELy

Answer (score 3):

The second arrow element should have `probability_inputs_arrow` as id and not `probability_arrow`, as you're building its id in the function as `id + '_arrow'` and you pass `'probability_inputs'`.

Comment: Thank you - that explains why the arrow wasn't toggling between pointing down and right.  Unfortunately, upon loading the page, I still require 2 clicks in order to toggle the second div.

Comment: I would change `if(tag.display == 'none'){` to `if (tag.display != 'block'){`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this then switches the "two click error" to the top div.

Answer (score 1):

actually you are getting error here

[image]

The second element need to have have `probability_inputs_arrow` as id and not `probability_arrow`,

Comment: Thank you - that explains why the arrow wasn't toggling between pointing down and right. Unfortunately, upon loading the page, I still require 2 clicks in order to toggle the second div.

Comment: @LizMacfie Reload your page and before you click the element, inspect it in your console. I wouldn't be surprised if your "display" style isn't set initially, and your `else` block is running. That would explain the click issue.

Comment: Both divs have the display style set initially in the CSS, as shown above.  Removing these initial settings results in both div toggles requiring two clicks.

Answer (score 1):

The style.display is set to "" by default when the page loads for the first time, thus it ends up in the else block and then requires a second click to go to the if block. Just add this to your else if statement.

```
<script>  
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV"); 
    if (x.style.display == "none") 

     {
   x.style.display = "block";
  }

    else if((x.style.display == 'null')||(x.style.display == ""))
  {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
  else
  {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was due to the default state of the DIV. Even if you set the DIV class value is set display: none, it appears some browser do not accept this state, and therefore it is unknown.

To solve the problem, using your own code, add another condition of default:

```
 var toggleDiv = function(id){
 var tag = document.getElementById(id).style;
     if(tag.display == 'none')
       {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById(id + '_arrow').className='arrow_down';
       } 
     else  if(tag.display == 'block') 
      {            
       document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
       document.getElementById(id + '_arrow').className='arrow_right';
      }
     else
       {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById(id + '_arrow').className='arrow_down';
       }
```

};
`